Enabling experimental features in exported FMU's (fmuExperimental)
I am using FMI4Cpp to run FMU's exported from openmodelica.
I would like to be able to serialize the state of an FMU to use it later for fast and precise initialization, but the FMU's that i generate from openmodelica (1.21.0) does not have the feature enabled, from modelDescription.xml:
canGetAndSetFMUstate="false"
canSerializeFMUstate="false"
As far as i can understand from the documentation i need to enable experimental features (fmuExperimental), but i cannot figure out how to do that?
I have tried to find a way to add the fmuExperimental compiler flag to the FMU build command line but did not succeed.

OpenModelica 1.21.0 does not support that feature, you have to download the latest OpenModelica version, probably the nightly build version https://openmodelica.org/download/download-windows/ and then from OMEdit you can set the flag by clicking SimulationSetup->Translation Flags->Additional Translation Flags and in the text box you can put -d=fmuExperimental something like below

and export the fmu it should work.
